# Why does this query string parameter not work on mobile?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, query-string

This works nicely on desktop.
If url is http://.....com?popup=true,
then the popup shows, else it is hidden.

But it always shows on mobile - any ideas why?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {
                //lots of functions...
                function get4(name) {
                    if (name = (new RegExp('[?&amp;]' + encodeURIComponent(name) + '([^&amp;]*)')).exec(location.search))
                    {
                        return decodeURIComponent(name[1]);
                    }
                }
                var popup = get4('popup');
                if (popup == "true")
                {
                    $('.pop_up').show();
                }
                else
                {
                    $('.pop_up').hide();
                }
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <!--html for popup-->
        <div class="pop_up" style="display:none;">
            ...
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: ([^&amp;]*)')).exec(location.search))  where's the starting inverted comma?

Comment: oh sorry I had edited this a little to hard. The inverted comma is actually there in my code:
if(name=(new RegExp('[?&amp;]'+encodeURIComponent(name)+'=([^&amp;]*)')).exec(location.search))

Comment: Add it in your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try below JavaScript code.

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
        var arrQueryStringParams = window.location.href.slice(window.location.href.indexOf('?') + 1).split('&');
        if (arrQueryStringParams.indexOf("popup=true") > -1)
        {
            $('.pop_up').show();
        }
        else
        {
            $('.pop_up').hide();
        }
    });
```